# How to get score from correct answer through form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a quiz that contains 10 questions: 5 multiple choice through radio input and 5 written answers through text input. See code for both inputs below. But I would also like to add a score system to these questions. I found a nice script here on stack overflow that can keep the score while user enters form input. I will add it below.

The script I use to check answers from radio input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('input[name=radio1]').change(function(){
     $('.alert').remove();
    if($('input[name=radio1]:checked').val() === "1") {
      $(this).parent().append('<span class="correct">✓ Correct!</span>');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append('<span class="incorrect">✗ Correct answer = B</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

The correct anser given is based on `value="1"`. The other answers have `value="0"`.

The script I use to check answers from text input:

```
$('submit').on('click', function() {
    markAnswers(1)
});

var answers = {
  q1: ["Auto's"]
};

function markAnswers(id) {
  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {

    let userAnswer = this.value.replace(/[^\w\'\,\-\?\!\"\:\—\;]/g,'');

    if ($.inArray(userAnswer, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br><span class='incorrect'>✗ Correct answer = ${answers[this.id]}</span>`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><span class='correct'>✓ Correct!</span>");
    }
  });
}
```

The correct value from text input is determined by this script above.

Now, the script I found that keeps the score, collects score through `data-score=`. But I was thinking to just use `value` instead. See original script below:

```
$('.track').change(function(e) {
    update_progress();
});

// supports any number of inputs and calculates done as %

function update_progress() {
    var score = 0
    $('input.track').each(function(){
      var _score = $(this).data("score")
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
          score += _score
        }
      })
  $('#score').text(score)
    var count = $('.track').length;
    var length = $('.track').filter(function() {
    return this.value;
}).length;
    var done = Math.floor(length * (100 / count));
    $('.perc').text(done);
    $('.meter').width(done + "%");
}
```

The script can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297288/4546157
It is really nice. It keeps the score but it also shows you if you have completed the form or not.

I would like each correct answer to have a value of 1 so at the end of the quiz the user can have a maximum score of 10/10. But, a big but, I don't know how to implement it. Hoping to see suggestions or solutions from you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would do it something like this. Though it's bad practice to use globally available variables, but for the sake of simplicity i put them there. Better to wrap everything in a div and store score/progress as data attributes.

Pen: https://codepen.io/lenadax/pen/QWQqMxP?editors=1111

```js
// global vars, put them somewhere else
var progress = 0;
var score = 0;

$('form.question').each(function(i, el) {
  // I'm lazy so form id is the same as input name for each question
  let inputs = $(`input[name=${$(this).attr('id')}]`);

  inputs.on('change', function() {
    // increase progress by 1 if button has been selected.
    progress++;
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
        // increase score if correct choice selected
        score++;
        $('<span class="result correct">').text('✓ Correct!').appendTo(el);
    } else {
        $('<span class="result incorrect">').text('X Incorrect!').appendTo(el);
    }
    // get number of questions
    let question_count = $('form.question').length;
    // disable after choosing for less hassle
    inputs.prop('disabled', true);
    
    // calculate the progress in percent
    let progress_num = progress / question_count * 100;
    $('.perc').text(progress_num);
    $('#score').text(`${score} / ${question_count}`);
   });
})
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:10px 5px;
}

.result {
  display: block;
}

.result.incorrect {
  color: red;
}

.result.correct {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
  <form class="question" id="question1">
    <span>Question 1</span>
    </p>
    <input name="question1" id="answer1" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="answer1">Wrong answer</label>
    </p>
    <input name="question1" id="answer2" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="answer2">Right answer</label>
  </form>
  <form class="question" id="question2">
    <span>Question 2</span>
    </p>
    <input name="question2" id="answer1" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="answer1">Wrong answer</label>
    </p>
     <input name="question2" id="answer2" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="answer2">Wrong answer</label>
    </p>
    <input name="question2" id="answer3" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="answer3">Right answer</label>
  </form>
  <h5>Done <span class='perc'>0</span>%</h5>
  <h5>Score <span id="score">0</span></h5>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lalena This looks good. The only thing that is missing though is getting a score from a correct answer that has been entered through text input.  But nonetheless, it looks good. Thank you!